# Web Scraping with two tables in a Website using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

Q: Using beautiful soup extract the table with Tesla Quarterly Revenue and store it into a dataframe named tesla_revenue. The dataframe should have columns Date and Revenue. Make sure the comma and dollar sign is removed from the Revenue column.

I am using the following code for this:

```
tesla_revenue = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date", "Revenue"])

for row in soup.find("tbody").find_all("tr"):

   col = row.find_all("td")
   date =col[0].text
    revenue = col[1].text.replace("$", "").replace(",", "")

tesla_revenue = tesla_revenue.append({"Date":date, "Revenue":revenue},ignore_index=True)
```

**The code works for only the first table "Tesla Annual Revenue" but does not retrieve "Tesla Quarterly Revenue" table**

URL is given: https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue?cm_mmc=Email_Newsletter-

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
revenue = soup.find_all("table", attrs={"class": "historical_data_table table"})

table = revenue[1]
body = table.find_all("tr")
head = body[0]
body_rows = body[1:]

all_rows = []
for row_num in range(len(body_rows)):
    row = []
    for row_item in body_rows[row_num].find_all("td"):
        clean = row_item.text.replace("$", "").replace(",", "")
        
        row.append(clean)
    all_rows.append(row)

tesla_revenue = pd.DataFrame(data=all_rows, columns=["Date", "Revenue"])
tesla_revenue
```